# stop insertion into the database after pressing refresh button in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a code in php and I'm performing inset operation into the database.Insert is going on perfectly but the problem is when I am pressing refresh button after insert operation, the same data is getting uploading again and again in the database. I tried this by creating session variable and storing submit value in that session and comparing both the values.If both values match then there will be no insert operation and vice versa. Here is my code:-

```
case 'insert' :
                        $_SESSION['value']=$_POST['Submit']
          if($_SESSION['value']!=$_POST['Submit'])
          {
              if (($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/gif")
             || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
             || ($_FILES["upload"]["type"] == "image/png" )
             && ($_FILES["upload"]["size"] < 10000))
               {
                $image= $_FILES["upload"]["name"];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["upload"]["tmp_name"],"E:/wamp/www/prakash/file_upload/" . $_FILES["upload"]["name"]);
                echo $sql="INSERT  INTO user SET
                                    lastname='$last_name',
                                    firstname='$first_name',
                                    sex='$gender',
                                    image='$image',
                                    hobbies='$hobby',
                                    addres='$address',
                                    cityy='$city',
                                    user_date=now()";
                                    mysql_query($sql);
                                    echo $user_id=mysql_insert_id();
        $sql="INSERT  INTO login SET
                                    user_id='$user_id',
                                    username='$user_name',
                                    password='$pass'";
                                     mysql_query($sql);
                                    // $_SESSION['submit'] = $_POST['Submit'];


               }
          else
               {
                 echo "Files must be either JPEG, GIF, or PNG and less than 10,000 kb";
               }

        }
        else{echo"data has been already Submitted";}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong or my logic is false....I want to do this thing with session only...Your answers r totaaly welcome

Comment: You appear to have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) in this code because you're not [properly escaping values](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Also, the deprecated `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications because it's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Be sure to have a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) to avoid making these sorts of mistakes.

Comment: Also worth noting: Plaintext passwords are **super** bad.

Comment: This line seems to be contradicting your first conditional statement `if($_SESSION['value']!=$_POST['Submit'])`

Comment: You will never enter the first `if` block because you are explicitly setting `$_SESSION['value']` to `$_POST['Submit']` right before it.

Comment: what should I can do...looking for the code

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid re-submits by changing your flow:

**HTML or form.php - whatever you named it**

```
<form action="submit_process.php" method="POST">
    <input name="username">
    <input name="password">
    <!-- blah blah blah -->
</form>
```

**submit_process.php**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `TABLE_NAME` (`username`,`password`) values ('".$_POST['username']."', '".$_POST['password']."')";

if(mysql_query($sql))
{
    header('Location: success.php');
}
else
{
    header('Location: fail.php');
}
```

**NOTE**

There are various grave issues with your code but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: I dont want to do this by using redirecting function....If u have any idea abt how to do this with the help of session thn pls tell me